# display selected process in textbox

Tags: vb.net, basic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXW95.png
When I click select, it opens up Form2 where the processes are getting listed. How should I go for selecting a process in Form2, then after pressing the select button display it in Form1's textbox?

That's how I get my processes

```
    Dim plist() As Process = Process.GetProcesses()

    For Each prs As Process In plist
        ListBox1.Items.Add(prs.ProcessName + "         (" + prs.PrivateMemorySize64.ToString() + ")")
    Next
```

Comment: We don't know what any of that is. Please post more information and code.

Comment: its a dll injector, i dont think you would need more code. i just to get form2's process listbox's selected process' name on form1's textbox

Comment: Maybe set the `TextBox` text to the selected item's name?

Comment: Yeah, looking for that code. I dont know whats the code for selected item and how should I set Form1's textbox from Form2

Comment: I still do not know what your DLL injector does nor what that program is. You'll have to provide more info and code. Your question appears too broad.

Comment: I hope you can understand it like this: https://i.imgur.com/aq7oQYY.png
in the meantime I could make it show it on form2, but I need the value on form1

   `Private Sub SteamButton1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SteamButton1.Click
        SteamTextBox1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
    End Sub`

Comment: That image does not tell what the program is, does, where It's from nor does not give enough information in general. But I'm glad that you've found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out
Form2:

```
    Private Sub SteamTheme1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim plist() As Process = Process.GetProcesses()

    For Each prs As Process In plist
        ListBox1.Items.Add(prs.ProcessName)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub SteamButton1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SteamButton1.Click

    Form1.SteamTextBox2.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: This only works either because (1) Form1 is the "startup object" for your application, or (2) You displayed Form1 initially without using the "new" keyword.  The proper way to accomplish this would be to either (A) Pass a reference to Form1 into Form2, or (B) display Form2 with ShowDialog() and retrieve the selected value when it is closed.